# Replace Some Variable Values with Variable Names

Tags: r

A package ('related') requires me to change some values withing variables in a largeish SNP dataframe (385x12300). This is no doubt simple but I can't find this particular question anywhere.  Sample data:

```
binfrom<-c(1,1,1,1,0,NA)
x <- sample(binfrom, 100, replace = TRUE)
x<-data.frame(matrix(x,10,10))
```

I need the variable names X1,X2 etc to replace each "1" in that variable column. The values "0" and "NA" remain unchanged.

Comment: Did you meant to use `NA` instead of a character `"NA"`

Comment: Yes, sorry newbie mistake in creating toy data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We convert the columns of 'x' to `character` class from `factor` and use `Map` to `replace` 1 in each column with the corresponding column name.

```
x[] <- lapply(x, as.character)
x[] <- Map(function(y,z) replace(y, y==1, z), x, colnames(x))
```

---

In the OP's post, `NA` was created as character `"NA"`. Because of that, the columns were `factor` while creating `data.frame` (with `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` - default option).  If we used real NA, then the first step i.e. converting to `character` is not needed.

---

In case, we work with `data.table`, another option is `set` which should be fast when working with large datasets.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)
for(j in seq_along(x)){
  set(x, i=NULL, j= j, value= as.character(x[[j]]))
  set(x, i= which(x[[j]]==1 & !is.na(x[[j]])), 
       j=j, value= names(x)[j])
}
```

NOTE: Assumption is that we are working with real `NA` values.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. But now on my real data where rownames are a mixed bag (eg: 12,13, 14, A6,A7) it only Maps the rows beginning with a letter. I have tried a few things but no luck.

Comment: Thank you @akrun. Stray whitespace was my real data problem.

Comment: How could I alter the replace function to insert  column number rather than name? Or should this be a separate question?

Comment: @dnatheist  In the second piece of code, remove the first `set` line and also in the second `set`, use `value = j`

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to use `which` (I'm assuming you have real `NA`s there- see @akruns comment)

```
indx <- which(x == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
x[indx] <- names(x)[indx[, 2]]
```

This is basically identifies the locations of ones and replacing with the corresponding column names while using the columns location of the generated index.